# ObjectDataSource 'VacancyObjectDataSource' could not find a non-generic method 'GetVacancy' that has parameters: VacancyID, Language, Status

Tags: c#, asp.net, dataset

I have an objectdatasource like this:

```
 <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="VacancyObjectDataSource" runat="server" SelectMethod="GetVacancy" 
        TypeName="HRcomgeWebApp.DataLayer.DataSets.MainDataSetTableAdapters.ViewVacancyTableAdapter" OnSelecting="VacancyObjectDataSource_Selecting" OnSelected="VacancyObjectDataSource_Selected">
        <SelectParameters> 
            <asp:Parameter Name="VacancyID" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Language" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Status" Type="Int32" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

and a formview like this:

```
<asp:FormView ID="VacancyFormView" runat="server" DataKeyNames="VacancyID" DataSourceID="VacancyObjectDataSource"
        CellPadding="0" CellSpacing="0" GridLines="None" BorderStyle="NotSet" width="100%">
```

..

my xsd code is like this:

```
[global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
        [global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Data.Design.TypedDataSetGenerator", "4.0.0.0")]
        [global::System.ComponentModel.Design.HelpKeywordAttribute("vs.data.TableAdapter")]


[global::System.ComponentModel.DataObjectMethodAttribute(global::System.ComponentModel.DataObjectMethodType.Select, true)]
    public virtual MainDataSet.VacancyDataTable GetVacancy(global::System.Nullable<int> VacancyID) {
        this.Adapter.SelectCommand = this.CommandCollection[0];
        if ((VacancyID.HasValue == true)) {
            this.Adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters[1].Value = ((int)(VacancyID.Value));
        }
        else {
            this.Adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters[1].Value = global::System.DBNull.Value;
        }
        MainDataSet.VacancyDataTable dataTable = new MainDataSet.VacancyDataTable();
        this.Adapter.Fill(dataTable);
        return dataTable;
    }
and this one

[global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]


    [global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Data.Design.TypedDataSetGenerator", "4.0.0.0")]
        private void InitCommandCollection() {
            this._commandCollection = new global::System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand[1];
            this._commandCollection[0] = new global::System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand();
            this._commandCollection[0].Connection = this.Connection;
            this._commandCollection[0].CommandText = "dbo.hr_GetVacancy";
            this._commandCollection[0].CommandType = global::System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            this._commandCollection[0].Parameters.Add(new global::System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@RETURN_VALUE", global::System.Data.SqlDbType.Int, 4, global::System.Data.ParameterDirection.ReturnValue, 10, 0, null, global::System.Data.DataRowVersion.Current, false, null, "", "", ""));
            this._commandCollection[0].Parameters.Add(new global::System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@VacancyID", global::System.Data.SqlDbType.Int, 4, global::System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, 10, 0, null, global::System.Data.DataRowVersion.Current, false, null, "", "", ""));
            this._commandCollection[0].Parameters.Add(new global::System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@Language", global::System.Data.SqlDbType.Int, 4, global::System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, 10, 0, null, global::System.Data.DataRowVersion.Current, false, null, "", "", ""));
            this._commandCollection[0].Parameters.Add(new global::System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@Status", global::System.Data.SqlDbType.Int, 4, global::System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, 10, 0, null, global::System.Data.DataRowVersion.Current, false, null, "", "", ""));
            this._commandCollection[0].Parameters.Add(new global::System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@ShowOld", global::System.Data.SqlDbType.Bit, 1, global::System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, 1, 0, null, global::System.Data.DataRowVersion.Current, false, null, "", "", ""));
        }
```

but I am getting this error

```
ObjectDataSource 'VacancyObjectDataSource' could not find a non-generic method 'GetVacancy' that has parameters: VacancyID, Language, Status.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: ObjectDataSource 'VacancyObjectDataSource' could not find a non-generic method 'GetVacancy' that has parameters: VacancyID, Language, Status.
```

Comment: The code you posted presents a GetVacancy method with only one parameter, shouldn't it have the Language and Status also?

Comment: may be that is the problem. how can i add more parameters using visual studio?

Comment: How did you add the `VacancyID` one?

Comment: actually i am working on this project developed by some one and first time using types dataset. I see XSD designer

Comment: I see, you probably gonna have to change the table definition on the dataset designer. I haven't worked with dataset also.